# Injecting an object that uses builder pattern inside spring constructor

Tags: java, spring, square-connect, square

I've seen this question asked a lot on here, but none of the answers have helped me in my situation.

I'm using [square sdk](https://github.com/square/connect-java-sdk) which prompts me to create the client like this, before using it.

```
import com.squareup.square.SquareClient;
import com.squareup.square.Environment;

SquareClient square = new SquareClient.Builder()
    .environment(Environment.SANDBOX)
    .accessToken("YOUR_SANDBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN")
    .build();
```

Given the service looks something like this, spring will **not able to find the required bean**. And will give an error like,

> No qualifying bean of type 'squareClient'

So the question I have is how to **load the two paramters** into the service **using dependecy injection** in order to make *square service* testable.

```
@Service
public class SquareService {
    private final SquareClient squareClient;

    public SquareService(SquareClient squareClient) {
        this.squareClient = squareClient;
    }
}
```

And my test I have

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    sut = new SquareService(new SquareClient.Builder()
    .environment(Environment.SANDBOX)
    .accessToken("YOUR_SANDBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN")
    .build());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `@Configuration` class and create the bean manually:

```
@Configuration
public class SquareConfiguration {

  @Value("${my.config.sandboxAccessToken}")
  private String sandboxAccessToken;

  @Bean
  public SquareService createSquareService(){
    return new SquareService(new SquareClient.Builder()
      .environment(Environment.SANDBOX)
      .accessToken(this.sandboxAccessToken)
      .build());
  }
}
```

Comment: If I have other dependencies being passed to the constructor I now have to set that up in the SquareConfiguration class also?

Comment: You can pass these arguments (If they are beans themselves) to the @bean-method: `public SquareService createSquareService(MyComponent myComponent)...`